# What is wrong with this sort routine?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lexicographic

I have an array of JavaScript objectss that have a string description. I am trying to implement a simplified sorting algorithm that will drop case, strip out HTML tags, and then strip out everything but letters and digits. I have:

```
DASHBOARD.todo_entries.sort(function(first, second)
  {
  var first_workbench = first.description.toLowerCase();
  var second_workbench = second.description.toLowerCase();
  first_workbench = first_workbench.replace(/<.*?>/, '');
  second_workbench = second_workbench.replace(/<.*?>/, '');
  first_workbench = first_workbench.replace(/[^_\w]/, '');
  second_workbench = second_workbench.replace(/[^_\w]/, '');
  console.log('"' + first_workbench + '", "' + second_workbench + '"');
  return (first_workbench > second_workbench);
  });
```

At present that is consistently generating a sort order with descriptions of:

```
Testing: d.
Testing: e.
Test: a.
Testing: f.
Test: c.
Test: b.
Testing: g.
Testing: b.
Testing: a.
Test: d.
Testing: c.
Testing: h.
Testing: i.
Testing: j.
Testing: k.
Testing: l.
```

What I'd expect to happen is that it would have "Test: [a-d]" appearing in order, and then "Testing: [a-l]" appearing in order.

I'm not sure how to code something that would naturally generate this order; it doesn't match their order of creation (I think the creation times/order of "Test: [a-d]" and "Testing: [a-l]" overlap, but they were individually created in sequential order).

I am getting similar, but not identical, results if I just set the function to compare the unaltered descriptions with either < or >. At least within "Test"/"Testing", an unaltered lexicographic search should coincide with the results of the search I want. I've searched a bit through my code and not found anything else obviously tampering with the ordering of that array.

Anything jump out as wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You know you can chain like this `.toLowerCase().replace().replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS `Array.sort` method takes a comparator function `cmp(a, b)` that should return `1` or another positive number (indicating `a < b`), `-1` or another negative number (indicating `b > a`), or `0` (indicating equivalent values) - see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Yours returns a boolean, effectively only `1` or `0`, so it won't sort correctly.

Try

```
return first_workbench === second_workbench ? 0 :
    first_workbench > second_workbench ? 1 : -1;
```

or similar.

Comment: And with that, we're sorting exactly as desired. I was thinking about virtually every step of the comparison except returning a <=> value.